# PowerShell and Google Calendar - 400 Error when creating event

Tags: powershell, calendar, google-calendar-api

so this'll be the first time posting on the Google Dev Forum, fingers crossed I can get this resolved as I am pulling my hair out!

I have the following script in PowerShell. I have sorted the OAuth2 and I am able to hit my Calendar API and see the hits in the dashboard. So, authentication is fine. I used the API Explorer to get a rough idea of what I would need to send in order to create a new Calendar event, but in doing so I get a 400 error.

Here's the section I am running:

```
$requestUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/mysite@blah.com/events?"

$body=@{
end='dateTime:2017-06-07T08:30:00+01:00'
start='dateTime:2017-06-07T08:00:00+01:00'
}


$json = $body | ConvertTo-Json

$header=@{Authorization = "Bearer $($tokens.access_token)"}

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Uri $requestUri -Method POST -Body 
$json -ContentType 'application\json' -TransferEncoding gzip
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
 Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

$json is formed like this:

```
{
    "end":  "dateTime:2017-06-07T08:30:00+01:00",
    "start":  "dateTime:2017-06-07T08:00:00+01:00"
}
```

I can remove transferEncoding and I get the same error.

As always, any help would be great :)

thanks

Comment: WOW!

That solved it. Always something so simple!!

Thank you :)

How do I mark as Answered, thats my next challenge!!

Comment: Well, I have one thing out standing in that I had to pass $body as follows:

    $body='{
"end": {
  "dateTime": "2017-06-07T15:00:00Z"
 },
"start": {
  "dateTime": "2017-06-07T10:00:00Z"
 }
}'

My original $body converted to json returned a 400 error, stating the end date was missing (ran it from the OAuth 2.0 Playground)

{
  "error": {
    "code": 400, 
    "message": "Missing end time.", 
    "errors": [
      {

Comment: Oh good!  You can't mark a comment as answered, I didn't think that would really be it. I've now made it a proper answer, and you can tick the green tick on the left of it to mark it as an answer. And upvote it too, if you want.

Comment: Marked as answered. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer, the `-ContentType` looks weird with a backslash in it, and maybe it should be a forward slash, e.g.

```
$json -ContentType 'application/json'
```